# Is it possible to pass a full array by reference?

Tags: excel

I have a plugin that provides some really powerful connections to an external API.

One of the parameters I need is an array, but as far as I know, there's no way to reference it! I need to have an actual array in the formula!

Here's what it looks like:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/dZOt1lO.png]

I would like a named reference to replace the array of string literals in the formula.

So instead of

```
=NSGLABAL("Subsidiary", {"400000", "400010"}, "Sep 2017" ...)
```

I want to write

```
=NSGLABAL("Subsidiary", RevenueAccounts, "Sep 2017" ...)
```

Where RevenueAccounts is a named reference.

The referenced data can be formatted in any manner, be it a range of cells, already formatted as an array `{"400000", "400010"}`, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: An Excel function like SUM or MAX will accept a named range just as in your example. Apparently your plugin only recognizes the array if it's in the curly brackets.

Comment: How do I pass a named range array to SUM?

 I tried SUM(A1) where A1 was {1, 2, 3} -- and the result was 1. However, SUM({1, 2, 3}) correctly returns 6.

Comment: Sum(NamedRange) will sum up the named range "NamedRange"

Comment: what if A1 is `={1,2,3}` ?